# Need basic help fixing external CSS stylesheet pathing in a Flask application

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Sorry for asking such a basic question, but I'm stuck and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am developing a small website using Flask, teaching myself web coding along the way.

I have the following file structure:

```
mathsoc
    mathsoc.py
    mathsoc/templates
        mathsoc.css
        mathsoc_main.html
```

My `mathsoc.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
    app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template('mathsoc_main.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then `mathsoc_main.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mathsoc.css"/>
    <title>Some Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
Hello World!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And `mathsoc.css` looks like this:

```
#content {
    width:46em;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But `mathsoc_main.html` cannot find the stylesheet, it appears: it does not apply either of the defined properties to the content. I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mathsoc.css"/>`, but I don't know what. It seems so blindingly obvious, yet no style is loaded!

Comment: the default name to store the templates in the dir is to name that dir as `templates`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your folder structure to include a static folder.

```
mathsoc
    mathsoc.py
    templates
        mathsoc_main.html
    static
        mathsoc.css
```

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/folders/

Comment: Thanks. Creating a `static` folder and moving the css file there, then using ` `href=static/mathsoc.css`, worked for me.